# Surjectivity of the Artin Map vs Kronecker-Weber Theorem, Class Field Theory for $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, ramification

I have read that the main goal of Class Field Theory is to characterize all abelian extensions of a number field $K$ in terms of parameters of $K$ only.

We know that for $K=\mathbb{Q}$, the Kronecker-Weber Theorem says that any abelian extension is contained inside some cyclotomic extension.

We know that for an abelian extension $L|K$, the Artin map is surjective.

What I want to know is this:

> > Let $K=\mathbb{Q}$. Are we getting any extra information about the abelian extensions of $K$ (which we cannot deduce from the Kronecker-Weber Theorem) from the fact that the artin map is surjective?

Comment: One deduces precisely the following extra information: for any integer $d$ and modulus $(a,d) = 1$, there exists a prime $p$ such that $p$ is $a$ modulo $d$. (From this one can then easily deduce Dirichlet's Theorem.)